# Ajax Pagination in Cakephp not setting page

Tags: ajax, cakephp, pagination

I have followed the [CakeBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#ajax-pagination) to create Ajax based pagination. The Links are all working, the routes are working because it is sending the request to the correct action on the controller.  I am getting the relevant page number in my controller action and I am then sending it to the Paginate helper to fetch the data. But that only ever returns the first page of results irrespective of the page being set.  So I did an override of the paginate function on the model and sure enough I am always getting the page set to 1.

Controller Action code..

```
public function reviews(){
   if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) { 
        if(!empty($this->params['page'])) {
            $review = $this->Page->find('first',     array('conditions'=>array('friendly'=>'reviews')));
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $this->paginate = array(
                'page' => $this->params['page'],
                'limit' => 3,
                'order' => array(
                    'Review.rating'=>'desc')
            );
            $reviews = $this->paginate('Review');       
            $this->set(compact('review','reviews'));
        }
} 
}
```

So how do I get the Paginator to use my page that I am sending it?

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the page, so you can remove that. Are you sure there's more than one page to show? Also, I don't see your paginate override.

Comment: Hi, I added the Page manually because it was always sending the first page.  I took the paginate override out. I only did it to see what page number it was being sent, which was always 1 and therefore concluded that the problem was in the controller not the model.

Comment: Pagination has nothing to do with the model :) The paginator simply sets the limit on a regular find call based on the pagination args. Are you sure there was a page 2? Did you look at the generated SQL as well?

Comment: There is a page 2.. I stuffed the database with loads of records to check that it worked.  Plus the paginate on the initial view works because it generates the page numbers etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay have found a solution.  The default for the pagination is to used named parameters. Which gives you URLs like blah/page:6.  I am not sure why but if you leave the Pagination array alone and do not set the page then it seems to ignore the page number in the request. So I changed the options in the pagination to

```
                $this->paginate = array('Review'=>array(
                'paramType' => 'querystring',
                'page' => $this->params['page'],
                'limit' => 3,
                'order' => array(
                    'Review.rating'=>'desc')
            ));
```

This then did not go through the routing properly and I was getting the wrong page from the AJAX request.  Which made me think it might have been a routing issue.... I did not follow this too far as I then just forced the route when creating the paging links by setting the Pagination options on the view to:-

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#tabReviews',
    'evalScripts' => true,
    "url"=>(array("controller"=>'home',"action"=>'reviews',"plugin"=>'tyres'))
));
```

This is now working so I am hoping that it helps someone else with the same problem.